# Automate firefox to click an appearing button

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, page-refresh

How can I make Firefox, or any other browser for that matter, refresh a site until it finds a certain button or javascript on the site, and then either run the javascript or use the mouse to click the button?

The page in question will be updated with a link or javascript button at an unknown time. I want to refresh it automatically until this link appears, and then click it. When the button is clicked or javascript is ran, I want to stop refreshing the page.

How can I automate this behavior? Even if it would be great to just start this process and then sit back and relax, a solution where I start the process (refresh) over and over again until the object is clicked, would also be good.

Also, could this be done even if I don't know what the javascript code would be when it appears or where on the page button will appear? And what if I know what and where? Is it possible?

My objective is just to click this button or excecute the javascript as fast as possible!

I've been trying everything I could think of, but I can't seem to get this to work. I would very much appreciate any help I could get!

Comment: So, like what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the best way to accomplish your goal, but if you aren't familiar with it, take a look at Selenium:  http://seleniumhq.org/